# UIStoryboard - OutletCollection

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

I am using nib files to build user interface, but now I switched to storyboard and I found one problem.

In the nib file, I have deployed 10 buttons and I used to participate buttons - `IBOutletCollection (UIButton *) NSArray`
The first button has 0 value, the second 2, and so on (in `OutletCollection Array`).

But using a UIStoryBoard buttons are placed randomly.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did to deal with this was I set the tags of the UIViews that I added to my outletcollection then added this to my viewDidLoad...

```
NSComparator compareTags = ^(id a, id b) {
                    NSInteger aTag = [a tag];
                    NSInteger bTag = [b tag];
                    return aTag < bTag ? NSOrderedAscending
                    : aTag > bTag ? NSOrderedDescending
                    : NSOrderedSame;
                };

self.UIViewCollection = [self.UIViewCollection sortedArrayUsingComparator:compareTags];
```

Now my UIViews are ordered 1-20. The outlet-collection is just an array of objects.